# How to set a variable name with space in python

Tags: python

Code has a variable name with space equal to variable value like this:

```
PC 1  =  "192.168.10.1"

PC 2  = "192.168.20.1"
```

When executing this getting:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How to resolve this ??

I dont have option to change the variable name to anyother. It will be `PC 1` (PC space 1) and assign ip address to this.

Comment: I don't understand, why would this ever be the case

Comment: You cannot use spaces in identifiers in Python.

Comment: Spaces aren't legal in variable names. Use an underscore `_` if you must. What's so bad about `PC1` as a variable name?

Comment: Why don't you have the option to change the variable name?

Comment: Hi @jamylak : We have a Front-end GUI, It is displaying as "PC 1". So in script I have to mention like above.I dont know how to map with this ??

Comment: `globals()['PC 1'] = "192.168.10.1"` if you insist :-)

Comment: @gmanikandan It displays as that, but your code obviously **does not** have a variable with spaces in it, the display is just different from the name for readability

Answer (score 5):

You can't have a variable name in source code with a space, but you can use a `dict`:

```
computers = {}
computers['PC 1'] = 'some ip'
computers['PC 2'] = 'other ip'
```

Comment: locals()['my cool var name'] = "my cool var value" is a fun hack for namepsaces but as far as I know there is no way to access the variable outside of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have spaces in variable names, for Python.

If you are going to parse the file as configuration file or something, let's try something like this:

ip.config:

```
PC 1 = "192.168.10.1"
PC 2 = "192.168.20.1"
```

ip.py

```
ip_config = {}
with open("ip.config") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split("=")
        ip_config[key.strip()] = value.strip(" \"\n")

print(ip_config["PC 1"])
print(ip_config["PC 2"])
```

Output:

```
192.168.10.1
192.168.20.1
```