# Is it possible to create an object with a space in python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to create an object named 'Stack Overflow' and is valued 5.

For example:

```
stack overflow = 5
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I get Syntax error obviously, but was wondering if there was a way

Comment: If you get a SyntaxError then the answer should be obvious... But you can refer to the official documentation too : https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Comment: Is there any language where this is even possible?

Comment: You can create an _object_ with a name attribute, and name anything you like. You can't create a _variable_ with a space in its name. Variable names don't have to match things real names.

Comment: most poeple just use underscores to emphatise that it shoud be a space, and then just lives with it being an underscore

Answer (score 1):

No. You will get a syntax error. You can however use spaces in the keys in a dict:

```
mydict = {}
mydict['stack overflow'] = 42
```

Comment: I know I will get a syntax error. But, was wondering if maybe there was a way.

Comment: @Berkay You cannot. It is simply not allowed. Please also see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769585/how-to-set-a-variable-name-with-space-in-python